# Conformal manifold of a supersymmetric field theory

Tags: definition, renormalization, conformal-field-theory, supersymmetry, effective-field-theory

I'm trying to understand what exactly is the conformal manifold of a theory. If I understand it right, the conformal manifold is the space of couplings.

1. From that point of view, it is just a subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$, where does the conformal structure comes from?
2. How is possible to prove that two different-looking theories lie on the same conformal manifold?

Comment: It's the space of *exactly marginal* couplings. I.e. those that lead to a beta function of zero and therefore take you from one CFT to another. That's why we call them conformal. Dualities between different looking theories on the same conformal manifold are usually conjectural. But the handful of proofs out there make essential use of supersymmetry.